# Qual é a relevância da Teoria das Categorias para a Ciência da Computação?

Tags: programação-funcional, ciência-da-computação

Estou estudando um pouco sobre programação funcional e não raro acabo me deparando com pessoas que falam sobre Teoria das Categorias, o que me faz pensar que pode ser algo com certa importância para a programação funcional.

Até onde [constatei](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_das_categorias), parece ser algo do campo da Matemática que eventualmente intercepta a Ciência da Computação. De fato, a Matemática é muito comum na nossa área, portanto isso não me causa estranheza.

Gostaria de ter uma ideia em quais tipos de situação a Teoria das Categorias pode ser relevante para a computação. É realmente *relevante* para a programação funcional?

Comment: Ixi! Me parece uma pergunta, apesar de bonita, fora de escopo.

Comment: @Sam, “ciência da computação em geral” faz parte do escopo do site ([veja aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)).

Comment: Não tenho estudo suficiente pra oferecer uma resposta completa, mas acredito que como a programação funcional se originou devido as necessidades dos matemáticos para resolução de problemas, logicamente ela anda bem junto a matemática

Comment: @LuizFelipe. Checa https://youtu.be/SmXB2K_5lcA?t=324 e https://youtu.be/I8LbkfSSR58. Podem ser úteis.

Comment: Tem um livro da UFRGS só sobre isso, e parece que é um dos poucos que há sobre o tema: https://www.traca.com.br/livro/885610/teoria-das-categorias-para-ciencia-computacao-vol12/

Comment: é usado no desenvolvimento de linguagens de programação, pra criar mecanismos de checagem de erro em tempo de compilação

Answer (score -4):

A teoria da Computação caracteriza-se pelo estudo formal dos processos de computação, suas capacidades e suas limitações, além
da relação entre as teorias comportamentais e o uso dos dispositivos automatizados. A teoria da computação torna-se primordial
para a ciência na medida em que, através de um sistema equacionado pela lógica, engenharia e matemática, proporciona conceitos
para encontrar a essência de uma implementação eficiente e, ainda, serve como base de raciocínio para a compreensão de uma
gama de fenômenos computacionais. Foi proposto o estudo de diversas áreas relacionadas à teoria da computação com o intuito
de comprovar sua importância no contexto tecnológico. Tais áreas são constituídas por conceitos básicos sobre formalismos,
máquinas de Turing, funções recursivas, solucionabilidade de problemas e outros. A partir do estudo desses conceitos, percebeuse a importância dos mesmos no sentido de fornecer suporte ao desenvolvimento de inúmeras aplicações práticas tais como
problemas NP, especificação e verificação de programas, análise sintática em compiladores, criptografia, análise de algoritmos
(complexidade computacional) e projeto de linguagens de programação de alto nível. (FAPERGS)

here is a book to help you better
https://www.amazon.com.br/Teoria-Categorias-Para-Ciencia-Computacao/dp/852410662X